# Can a Pathfinder Society adventure created for pregenerated characters be played without them?

Tags: published-adventures, pathfinder-society, pathfinder-2e, pregenerated-characters

Some Pathfinder Society adventures include pre-generated characters. For example, [Origin of the Open Road](https://paizo.com/products/btq01zna?Pathfinder-Society-Scenario-100-Origin-of-the-Open-Road) includes this text:

> *Origin of the Open Road* is a Pathfinder Society adventure designed for 5th-level pregenerated characters (Tier 5).

In these cases, is it Society legal to play using Tier 5 characters that are not pregenerated?

I've been reading in the organized play rules for PF2e, but I don't see anything which describes a requirement for using pregenerated characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that is not allowed. The adventure states on page 2:

> How to Play
>
> Origin of the Open Road is a Pathfinder Society Scenario designed for 5th-level pregenerated characters (Tier 5).

Likewise, on the [product page](https://paizo.com/products/btq01zna?Pathfinder-Society-Scenario-100-Origin-of-the-Open-Road) it states:

> A Pathfinder Society Scenario designed for level 5 pregenerated characters.

and

> This adventure makes use of the 5th-level pregenerated characters available as a free download.

Compare this to the language in a regular scenario:

> How to Play
>
> Pathfinder Society Scenario #1–01: The Absalom Initiation is a Pathfinder Society Scenario designed for 1st- through 4th-level characters (Tier 1–4; Subtiers 1–2 and 3–4).

In practice, you'll find the six level 5 pregens available are pretty well-suited to the scenario, it's *almost* like the scenario was written to showcase them.